# Eclipse C++ Header and Files Issues

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to create a class with a cpp file in Eclipse for C++ without the header? Also, is there a way to run a single file, without putting it in its own project or something? I searched online, but I was unable to find answers that answered by question completely.

Comment: If you want to run small tests, you can create a `quick_test` project with a single cpp file and then each time just paste the test code there and run.

Answer (score 1):

Re:

> Is there a way to create a class with a cpp file in Eclipse for C++ without the header?

Yes. You can put the class definition and the element functions' implementations into the same `.cpp` file.

Re:

> [...] is there a way to run a single file, without putting it in its own project or something?

- Select *Run* → *External Tools* → *External Tools Configurations...*
- Select the *New* button or *Right-click*  → *New*
- ...configure...
- Deactivate *Build* → *Build before launch* in case you don't want to

See also [Workbench User Guide > Tasks > Running external tools](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm&cp=0_3_14).